# Select value inside column python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column that contains

```
comment id , text , date ...
```

I only want to  select value comment_id and comment_text from column comments_full
is there a way I can do that?

this is my full code

```
#Import necessary libraries
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

for post in get_posts('page_name', cookies='C:/Users/stefa/OneDrive/Bureau/cookies.txt', extra_info=True, pages=2, options={"comments": True}):
    post_entry = post
    fb_post_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(post_entry, orient='index')
    fb_post_df = fb_post_df.transpose()
    post_df_full = post_df_full.append(fb_post_df)
    print(post['post_id']+' get')
#Check dataframe information, 47 data columns of Facebook post are being scraped
post_df_full.info()
#Display header of dataframe
post_df_full[["post_id","comments_full"]].head()
```

[image: the output of dataframe]

Comment: `df['comments_full'][index]` will give you the list of dictionary in the column at an index. then you can adddress `df['comments_full'][index][0]['comment_id']` . similarly `df['comments_full'][index][0]['comment_text']`

Comment: the name index is not difined that's the error :  NameError: name 'index' is not defined how can i difined index

Comment: index range from 0 to `number of rows.`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df.comments_full.apply(lambda x:x['comment_id'] + "|" + x['comment_text'])
```

Comment: i get this error : TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Please share your sample data

Comment: Comments_full : [{'comment_id': '433934735000014', 'comment_url': 'https://facebook.com/433934735000014', 'commenter_id': '100002886314120', 'commenter_url': 'https://facebook.com/loubnaharifi?fref=nf&rc=p&refid=52&__tn__=R', 'commenter_name': 'Loubna Harifi', 'commenter_meta': None, 'comment_text': 'Ã€ 18h Ã§a commence', 'comment_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 10, 0, 0),